# Запуск приложений в фоне

Tags: windows, консоль

Как запустить консольное приложение в фоне (без окна консоли, просто как процесс), аля:

> sass &

в *nix, но только под windows? Как вариант написать для этого прогу, но пока я ищу более простое решение :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такая утилитка [cmdow](http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/),она позволяет скрывать консольное окно.

Comment: Спасибо, работает.